# How can I optimize or reduce the time complexity of the following code in Laravel 5.2.45?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

In users table I have following data.

```
id   name    parent_id 
1     A           0
2     B           1
3     C           2
4     D           3
5     E           4
6     F           1
```

A have four level children. E is also children of A. E is the last, it has not any children. Now I can fetch all the children of any parent like the following code.

```
function getChildren($Id){
   $cache = [];
   $chList = [];
   $allUser = User::orderBy('parent_id', 'asc')
        ->orderBy('parent_id', 'asc')
        ->get();
   foreach($allUser as $user) {
    $cache [$user->parent_id][] = $user;        
   }
  $children0 = empty($cache [$Id]) ? [] : $cache [$Id];
  #first level child
  foreach($children0 as $child1) {

    $chList[$child1->id] = $child1;

    if(!empty($cache [$child1->id])) {

        #Second level child
        foreach($cache [$child1->id] as $child2) {

            $chList[$child2->id] = $child2;

            if(!empty($cache [$child2->id])) {

                #third level child
                foreach($cache [$child2->id] as $child3) {

                    $chList[$child3->id] = $child3;

                    if(!empty($cache [$child3->id])) {

                        #fourth level child
                        foreach($cache [$child3->id] as $child4) {
                            #can not be parent
                            $chList[$child4->id] = $child4;
                            
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

return $chList;
}
```

I can get the actual result by this code. But for huge data it is time consuming. Can any one help me to reduce time complexity or optimize the code?

Comment: It appears to be a "tree" structure, so you can build it in memory like a tree. Then traverse the tree to get what you need. This will eliminate all those "foreach"s per depth level.

Answer (score 0):

you can write a recursive CTE in MySQL, like this [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e62ac0f12f8c25a73818b6359babe12c).

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte1 AS (
    SELECT id, CAST(name AS CHAR(20)) name, parent_id
    FROM table1
    WHERE name='E'
    
    UNION ALL
    
    SELECT table1.id, CONCAT(cte1.name,table1.name), table1.parent_id
    FROM cte1
    INNER JOIN table1 ON table1.id = cte1.parent_id)
SELECT *
FROM cte1;
```

output:

| id | name | parent_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | E | 4 |
| 4 | ED | 3 |
| 3 | EDC | 2 |
| 2 | EDCB | 1 |
| 1 | EDCBA | 0 |

Above is a quick example of how it can work, but you can change it let it do what you want it to do.

Answer (score 0):

Build a tree from a root such as `parent_id == 0`. Then traverse the tree to get all the children.

```php
<?php

$users = [
    (object) [
        "id" => "1",
        "name" => "A",
        "parent_id" => "0"
    ],
    (object) [
        "id" => "2",
        "name" => "B",
        "parent_id" => "1"
    ],
    (object) [
        "id" => "3",
        "name" => "C",
        "parent_id" => "2"
    ],
    (object) [
        "id" => "4",
        "name" => "D",
        "parent_id" => "3"
    ],
    (object) [
        "id" => "5",
        "name" => "E",
        "parent_id" => "4"
    ],
    (object) [
        "id" => "6",
        "name" => "F",
        "parent_id" => "1"
    ]
];

function create_tree(&$list, $parents) {
    $tree = [];
    foreach ($parents as $parent) {
        if (isset($list[$parent->id])) {
            $parent->children = create_tree($list, $list[$parent->id]);
        }
        $tree[] = $parent;
    }
    return $tree;
}

function get_children($roots, $parent_id = null) {
    foreach ($roots as $parent) {
        if ($parent_id != null && $parent->id == $parent_id) {
            if (isset($parent->children)) {
                return get_children($parent->children);
            }
        } else if ($parent_id == null) {
            if (isset($parent->children)) {
                $children = get_children($parent->children);
                if (count($children) > 0) {
                    return array_merge($roots, $children);
                }
            }
            return $roots;
        } else {
            if (isset($parent->children)) {
                $children = get_children($parent->children, $parent_id);
                if (count($children) > 0) {
                    return $children;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return [];
}

$list = array_reduce($users, function ($carry, $user) {
    $carry[$user->parent_id][] = $user;
    return $carry;
}, []);

// assuming root of tree is parent_id == 0
$root_id = 0;
$tree = create_tree($list, $list[$root_id]);

$parent_id = 4;
$children = get_children($tree, $parent_id);

print_r($children);
```